# R Studio toggle for diagnostics

Tags: r, rstudio

I assume the R Studio [toggles for diagnostics](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205753617-Code-Diagnostics) are these, found at:

```
Tools > Global Options > Code > Diagnostics
```

[image]

I have everything selected identical to the image above. If I recall properly my R Studio used to underline misspellings (red squiggly maybe) and it would put exclamation marks and warning signs when my syntax was off in the margins. For some reason this has stopped lately. I'm on R Studio Preview version 1.2.1237.

How do I toggle these diagnostics (misspellings, syntax errors, etc.) back on?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. RStudio currently only supports diagnostics in a document, e.g. an `.R` file or an R Notebook. **Not in the console**. Just press `File` -> `New File` -> `R Script` (on Mac) to create a new script file.
2. Furthermore, you will need to **save the file** (in this case, the script) at least **once** for code diagnostics to analyse your code. You can see that in the menu you posted: *«Show diagnostics whenever source files are saved»* and *«Show diagnostics after keyboard is idle (...)»* (the latter only works in previously saved files)
3. If it still doesn't get triggered, try `Code` -> `Show Diagnostics` to show the `Markers` tab.

Unsaved file

[image: 1]

Saved file

[image: 2]